# MFA status for classic admins in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Users with ServiceAdministrator, AccountAdministrator and CoAdministrator roles are classic administrators in Azure.
We are trying to get MFA status for these classic administrator users. However, using '**Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName {classicAdminSignInName}**' in PowerShell, we are not getting any user in result.
Also the classic administrator users are not found when searching in Azure AD from Azure portal.
In respect to above scenario, can you please help us understand. How to get MFA status of classic administrator using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

This not how you get an ADUser UPN.
You'd do this...

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName SomeUserName@SomeDomain.com
```

... no need for the braces, unless you are going to use Where filtering.

```
Get-MsolUser | 
Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE" } | 
Select UserPrincipalName
```

Just as you would if you were doing this via Get-ADUser in on-prem ADDS.

Doing a search for your use case shows you items you need to be aware of:

['get azure user mfa status'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=get%20azure%20user%20mfa%20status&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=get%20azure%20user%20mfa%20status&sc=1-25&sk=&cvid=4E53F7A3027044A3851A3F3DF82AA028)

Example hits:

[Azure Multi-Factor Authentication user states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates)

[Powershell script to fetch list of users with MFA status](https://www.techmanyu.com/fetching-azure-ad-users-mfa-status-using-powershell)

[identify users that were MFA configured:](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/report-on-users-with-mfa-enabled/m-p/165807)

```
Get-MsolUser -all | 
select UserPrincipalName, 
@{N="MFA Status"; E={ if( $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.IsDefault -eq $true) {($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods|Where IsDefault -eq $True).MethodType} 
else { "Disabled"}}} | 
FT -AutoSize
```

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_6h67oJslWOHEx9j&Q_CHL=gl
>